# Invoke a No VPC Lambda function from a VPC Lambda function - Node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to invoke a No VPC Lambda function which sends an SES mail from VPC Lambda Function. But still SES is unable to connect with internet.

Here I don't want to attach NAT. So I am trying invoke NO VPC Lambda function.

### fruitsData (Within VPC)

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

    var params = {
        FunctionName: 'sendMail',
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        LogType: 'Tail',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({ "fruits" : fruits })
    };

    lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            context.fail(err);
        } else {
            context.succeed(data.Payload);
        }
    })
}
```

### sendMail (No VPC)

```
const charset = 'UTF-8';
 exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const message = JSON.stringify(event, null, 2);
    const params = {
       Source: source,
       Destination: {
           ToAddresses: [recipient.email]
       },
       Message: {
           Subject: {
               Data: "Example",
               Charset: charset
           },
           Body: {
               Text: {
                   Data: message,
                   Charset: charset
               },
               Html: {
                   Data: message,
                   Charset: charset
               }
           }
       }
   };
   try {
       await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
       callback(null, "Email sent successfully");
   }
   catch (ex) {
       console.log('Unhandled Exception', ex);
   }
};
```

**ERROR**

> Task timed out after 20.02 seconds

Comment: Did you tried increasing the timeout ? Or is SES sandbox disabled ? If SES is still sandboxed, first verify the email id to which you are sending the mail.

Comment: Have you enabled outbound traffic for the VPC?

Comment: @c1moore second one is without VPC.

Comment: Yes, but the first one has to start the second one, so it needs to be able to access the second one.

Comment: Specifically, you can refer to this comment on the AWS forums page: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=231990#jive-message-764003

Comment: Here I'm already able to send an email successfully by invoking the second one, if I put both functions in No VPC

Answer (score 0):

> Here I don't want to attach NAT. So I am trying invoke NO VPC Lambda
>   function.

That's not possible. Currently the only way a Lambda function inside a VPC can access anything outside the VPC is through a NAT.

Also note that your statement that the first function "needs to be able to access the second one" is incorrect. Lambda functions never access each other directly. The first function needs to access the AWS Lambda API, which it would use to trigger an invocation of the second function.

Answer (score -1):

You can check what's happening using

```
const sendEmail = ses.sendEmail(params).promise();

sendEmail
  .then(data => {
    console.log("email submitted to SES", data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

If you still face issue, You can check the following :-

1. Try increasing the timeout period of lambda.
2. Did you raised request to disable SES sandbox.
3. If not disabled, try with verified email id.

Comment: I increased the timeout, disabled SES sandbox and also trying with verified email addresses only. Still I'm getting the error.

Comment: Check, using the response received using promise call.